# Trying to test my app on iPhone iOS 6.1.2 but "No provisioned iOS devices..." error?

Tags: ios, xcode, version, device, provisioning

I have a big problem. I have an iPhone with iOS 6.1.2 and the latest version of Xcode - 4.6.1. When I try to test my app on that device, Xcode says that

> "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS
>   version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to
>   run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

Where is the problem and how to solve this? I tried going to Organizer, right click on device and adding device to provisioning profile, but no result. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might have problem with the provisioning profile installed on your Decvice or your device is not added as development device in your Organizer, check your Organizer in Xcode if you have valid provisioning profile within device and your device is added for as a development device

Comment: If you have upgraded the version of iOS recently, make sure you have checked the "Use for development" option in the Organizer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you try these methods:-

- Try clicking "Use for Development" on your device in the Xcode
  Organizer.
- Stupid but try this also closing and re-opening xcode.

I think these are going to help you..

Comment: Yes, "Use for Development" solved the problem. Thanks and sorry for my stupid question, but I am a new in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I am not sure :
Select your project Target->under the summery select the some low deployment target like 5.0 .
and see whether is it working .